# Help understanding example of not a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I'm working on grade 12 math and learning about inverse functions. So far I've learned that not all functions have inverse functions, but now my book's giving an example of such an invertible function that I don't understand. Here's an excerpt from the book (which can be found [here](https://www.siyavula.com/read/maths/grade-12/functions/02-functions-03#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20if%20the%20inverse%20is%20not)):

[image]

I don't understand why that inverse is not a function? The wording's confusing because it says it "cannot be written as $f^{-1}(x)=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}x}$ because it's not a function". But clearly it is written as that? What makes that not a function, while $f(x)=3x^2$ is a function? Why does it follow that "we write the inverse as $y=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}x}$" which somehow demonstrates that it's not a function? Should we also write $f(x)=3x^2$ as $y=3x^2$ ? And if so why? And why does *only* replacing the $f(x)$  with a $y$ demonstrate that something is or isn't a function?

Comment: A function assigns _only one_ value of $ \ y \ $ to a chosen value of $ \ x \ \ . \ $  What are the value(s) of, say, $ \ \pm \sqrt{\frac13 · 27} \ \ ? $  The function $ \ f(x) \ = \ 3x^2 \ , \ x \ \ge \ 0 \ \ $ _does_ have an inverse _function_ $ \ f^{-1}(x) \ = \ \sqrt{\frac13 x } \ \ $ because there is only one value from this function for any choice of $ \ x \ $ in its domain.  (The label $ \ y \ $ has nothing to do with deciding this.)

Comment: I'd argue "cannot" should be replaced with "should not".  If we abuse notation, we could write the inverse as $f^{-1}(x) = \pm \sqrt{\frac13x}$, but you really, _really_, shouldn't, as it will likely get you in trouble at some point, and errors of notation are really hard to find and correct when something goes wrong.

Comment: @BrianMoehring, I'd like to mark yours as the accepted answer. I think what tripped me up on the whole thing was that the excerpt makes it seem like notation can dictate what is and isn't a function, when in reality it just comes down to *-to-one is a function and should/can be written with function notation while *-to-many is *not* a function and shouldn't/can't be written with function notation, which I already knew.

Comment: There is a good example in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4504448/solve-x2y22z21-2-cos-z-for-z-near-0-1-0/4504523#4504523

Answer (score 4):

A function is defined as having exactly one output for each input in the domain.  The expression $\pm \sqrt{\frac 13x}$ does not provide a unique output for every input $x$, so it does not represent a function of $x$.

Comment: Hi Ross, I have a quick question after reading your post if you don't mind: given two variables $x$ and $y$, can we assume that the phrase "$y$ depends on $x$" usually means $y=f(x)$ for some function $f$? Thank you for your time.

Comment: @MathDoctor:   Yes, but the function may not have any nice formula.

Answer (score 2):

When they say $y = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}x}$ they are giving coordinate pairs. So every $x \geq 0$ value except $x = 0$ generates a pair (two coordinate pairs) of values: $\left[\left(x, \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}x}\right), \left(x, -\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}x}\right)\right]$.

That's why $f^{-1}(x)$ is *not* a function: because it is indeterminate which value (the positive or negative) the inverse should be, given an $x$ value. Instead of a many-to-one relationship (the original), we have a one-to-many, which by definition cannot be a function.

**Edit:** About domain and range

**boojum** correctly pointed out that this absolutely can be a one-to-one function (i.e. inverse is a function) if we restrict the original domain. We could say $f(x) = 3x^2, x \geq 0 \leadsto f^{-1}(x) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}x}$ or $f(x) = 3x^2, x \leq 0 \leadsto f^{-1}(x) = -\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}x}$.

**p.s.** So if you're wondering, well gee, if I know the "inverse" is $\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}x}$, isn't that "like an inverse". Well yes. The difference is that this inverse represents a [relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(mathematics)) (which a function is a subset of--i.e. a function *is also* a relation but a relation is not necessarily a function) and in this specific case a one-to-many relation (whereas a function represents either a one-to-one or many-to-one relation).